# How to get Mercure server to automatically push to event subscribers?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com, mercure

I have a quick test Symfony application running to try to integrate the Mercure protocol.

I have a test Mercure hub running with the following:

```sh
JWT_KEY='aVerySecretKey' ADDR='localhost:3000' ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1 CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=* ./mercure
```

I have a form that submits the data to the following endpoint:

```php
     /**
     * @Route("/resources", name="resourcesPost", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function resourcesPost(Publisher $publisher, Request $request){

        $user = $this->getUser();

        $update = new Update(
            'http://example.com/books/1',
            json_encode([
                'from' => $user->getFullName(),
                'sent at' => (new DateTime())->format('H:i:s'),
                'message' => $request->request->get('message'),
            ])
        );

        $publisher($update);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('resources');
    }
```

Once I hit the form I get the following in the debugger:

```sh
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2019:13:27:40 -0400] "GET /hub?topic=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fbooks%2F1&topic=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fbooks%2F2&topic=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Freviews%2F%7Bid%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "http://localhost:8888/resources" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows N
T 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
time="2019-06-19T13:32:50-04:00" level=info msg="Subscriber disconnected" remote_addr="127.0.0.1:65391"
time="2019-06-19T13:32:53-04:00" level=info msg="Update published" event_id=cd3acff1-7e9b-4e28-b6ba-e79aeb4c1791 remote_addr="127.0.0.1:49546"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2019:13:32:53 -0400] "POST /hub HTTP/1.0" 200 36 "" ""
time="2019-06-19T13:32:53-04:00" level=info msg="Event sent" event_id=cd3acff1-7e9b-4e28-b6ba-e79aeb4c1791 remote_addr="127.0.0.1:65384"
```

However, the javascript on the second browser that is listening, does not put the response in the console log :

```
  const u = new URL('http://localhost:3000/hub');
  u.searchParams.append('topic', 'http://example.com/books/1');
  // Subscribe to updates of several Book resources
  u.searchParams.append('topic', 'http://example.com/books/2');
  // All Review resources will match this pattern
  u.searchParams.append('topic', 'http://example.com/reviews/{id}');

  const es = new EventSource(u);
  let lastEventId = null;
  es.onmessage = e => {
       let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
       lastEventId = e.lastEventId;
       console.log(data);
  }
```

If I go into the back into the terminal and run `ctrl+c` (to kill the Mercure server) the data will then get pushed into the javascript. My question is how do I get it to automatically push the data to the javascript without having to kill the Mercure server (running on localhost:3000) and then restart it?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/dunglas/mercure/issues/105

The following steps fix the issue for some users:

- Run Mercure with `ADDR=":3000" ./mercure.exe` (the Hub will be available on port 3000)
- Be sure that `mercure.exe` is whitelisted in Windows' firewall